# The name 'LabelFor' does not exist in current context in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor, visual-studio-2013

I upgrade the visual studio 2010 MVC project to visual studio 2013 .Net 4.5.

When I tried to add the following declaration to it, I get an error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.PasswordFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I checked the references, all of them are in place. I added an web.config in view folder, but that didn't fix it.

[image]

Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Do you have the correct information in the web.config you placed in your view folder?  There are some important sections that missing would cause this error.

Comment: I recommend you create a new MVC project in VS2013 and compare web.configs (website root & the one under the Views folder) and the referenced assemblies and you make the proper adjustments to the migrated project. This is the approach I use.

Comment: Check your View's web.config <system.web.webPages.razor> under <namespaces>. Usually you get this compile errors when you are missing <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to MVC 5.1 I had a similar problem, fixed by updating the version of System.Web.WebPages.Razor from 2.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0 in the config section of views\web.config

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Comment: In VS2013:  "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2013 does nto support MVC3, only MVC 4:

[Visual Studio 2013 Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

> Visual Studio 2010 SP1 supports only MVC 2 and MVC 3, Visual Studio
>   2012 supports only MVC 3 and MVC 4, **and Visual Studio 2013 supports
>   only MVC 4**

This is why your getting these errors. You need to follow the [instructions to upgrade your MVC3 project to MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806)